# Can someone please explain the difference between "from socket import example" and "import socket"?

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, import, attributes

I'm new to Python and networking and I know my question may sound redundant, but I have spent hours researching the difference between `from socket import *` and `import socket` and the different types of socket objects. I am currently making a simple packet sniffer and have been getting lots of attribute errors. I have noticed that if I write `import socket` and execute `dir(socket)` I get:

```
AF_APPLETALK
AF_DECnet
AF_INET
AF_INET6
AF_IPX
AF_LINK
AF_ROUTE
AF_SNA
AF_SYSTEM
AF_UNIX
AF_UNSPEC
AI_ADDRCONFIG
AI_ALL
AI_CANONNAME
AI_DEFAULT
AI_MASK
AI_NUMERICHOST
AI_NUMERICSERV
AI_PASSIVE
AI_V4MAPPED
AI_V4MAPPED_CFG
AddressFamily
CAPI
CMSG_LEN
CMSG_SPACE
EAGAIN
EAI_ADDRFAMILY
EAI_AGAIN
EAI_BADFLAGS
EAI_BADHINTS
EAI_FAIL
EAI_FAMILY
EAI_MAX
EAI_MEMORY
EAI_NODATA
EAI_NONAME
EAI_OVERFLOW
EAI_PROTOCOL
EAI_SERVICE
EAI_SOCKTYPE
EAI_SYSTEM
EBADF
EWOULDBLOCK
INADDR_ALLHOSTS_GROUP
INADDR_ANY
INADDR_BROADCAST
INADDR_LOOPBACK
INADDR_MAX_LOCAL_GROUP
INADDR_NONE
INADDR_UNSPEC_GROUP
IPPORT_RESERVED
IPPORT_USERRESERVED
IPPROTO_AH
IPPROTO_DSTOPTS
IPPROTO_EGP
IPPROTO_EON
IPPROTO_ESP
IPPROTO_FRAGMENT
IPPROTO_GGP
IPPROTO_GRE
IPPROTO_HELLO
IPPROTO_HOPOPTS
IPPROTO_ICMP
IPPROTO_ICMPV6
IPPROTO_IDP
IPPROTO_IGMP
IPPROTO_IP
IPPROTO_IPCOMP
IPPROTO_IPIP
IPPROTO_IPV4
IPPROTO_IPV6
IPPROTO_MAX
IPPROTO_ND
IPPROTO_NONE
IPPROTO_PIM
IPPROTO_PUP
IPPROTO_RAW
IPPROTO_ROUTING
IPPROTO_RSVP
IPPROTO_TCP
IPPROTO_TP
IPPROTO_UDP
IPPROTO_XTP
IPV6_CHECKSUM
IPV6_DSTOPTS
IPV6_HOPLIMIT
IPV6_HOPOPTS
IPV6_JOIN_GROUP
IPV6_LEAVE_GROUP
IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS
IPV6_MULTICAST_IF
IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP
IPV6_NEXTHOP
IPV6_PKTINFO
IPV6_RECVTCLASS
IPV6_RTHDR
IPV6_RTHDR_TYPE_0
IPV6_TCLASS
IPV6_UNICAST_HOPS
IPV6_V6ONLY
IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP
IP_DEFAULT_MULTICAST_LOOP
IP_DEFAULT_MULTICAST_TTL
IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP
IP_HDRINCL
IP_MAX_MEMBERSHIPS
IP_MULTICAST_IF
IP_MULTICAST_LOOP
IP_MULTICAST_TTL
IP_OPTIONS
IP_RECVDSTADDR
IP_RECVOPTS
IP_RECVRETOPTS
IP_RETOPTS
IP_TOS
IP_TTL
IntEnum
LOCAL_PEERCRED
MSG_CTRUNC
MSG_DONTROUTE
MSG_DONTWAIT
MSG_EOF
MSG_EOR
MSG_OOB
MSG_PEEK
MSG_TRUNC
MSG_WAITALL
NI_DGRAM
NI_MAXHOST
NI_MAXSERV
NI_NAMEREQD
NI_NOFQDN
NI_NUMERICHOST
NI_NUMERICSERV
PF_SYSTEM
SCM_CREDS
SCM_RIGHTS
SHUT_RD
SHUT_RDWR
SHUT_WR
SOCK_DGRAM
SOCK_RAW
SOCK_RDM
SOCK_SEQPACKET
SOCK_STREAM
SOL_IP
SOL_SOCKET
SOL_TCP
SOL_UDP
SOMAXCONN
SO_ACCEPTCONN
SO_BROADCAST
SO_DEBUG
SO_DONTROUTE
SO_ERROR
SO_KEEPALIVE
SO_LINGER
SO_OOBINLINE
SO_RCVBUF
SO_RCVLOWAT
SO_RCVTIMEO
SO_REUSEADDR
SO_REUSEPORT
SO_SNDBUF
SO_SNDLOWAT
SO_SNDTIMEO
SO_TYPE
SO_USELOOPBACK
SYSPROTO_CONTROL
SocketIO
SocketKind
SocketType
TCP_MAXSEG
TCP_NODELAY
_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
_GiveupOnSendfile
_LOCALHOST
_LOCALHOST_V6
__all__
__builtins__
__cached__
__doc__
__file__
__loader__
__name__
__package__
__spec__
_blocking_errnos
_intenum_converter
_realsocket
_socket
create_connection
dup
errno
error
fromfd
gaierror
getaddrinfo
getdefaulttimeout
getfqdn
gethostbyaddr
gethostbyname
gethostbyname_ex
gethostname
getnameinfo
getprotobyname
getservbyname
getservbyport
has_ipv6
herror
htonl
htons
if_indextoname
if_nameindex
if_nametoindex
inet_aton
inet_ntoa
inet_ntop
inet_pton
io
ntohl
ntohs
os
selectors
setdefaulttimeout
sethostname
socket
socketpair
sys
timeout

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now if I change it to `from socket import *` I get:

```
__class__
__delattr__
__dir__
__doc__
__enter__
__eq__
__exit__
__format__
__ge__
__getattribute__
__getstate__
__gt__
__hash__
__init__
__le__
__lt__
__module__
__ne__
__new__
__reduce__
__reduce_ex__
__repr__
__setattr__
__sizeof__
__slots__
__str__
__subclasshook__
__weakref__
_accept
_check_sendfile_params
_closed
_decref_socketios
_io_refs
_real_close
_sendfile_use_send
_sendfile_use_sendfile
accept
bind
close
connect
connect_ex
detach
dup
family
fileno
get_inheritable
getpeername
getsockname
getsockopt
gettimeout
listen
makefile
proto
recv
recv_into
recvfrom
recvfrom_into
recvmsg
recvmsg_into
send
sendall
sendfile
sendmsg
sendto
set_inheritable
setblocking
setsockopt
settimeout
shutdown
timeout
type

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't get it. Why are they so different? When I have it imported one way, one thing has no attribute and when I import it another way, another thing has no attribute. It seems like one type of import accesses all the constants in the socket library while the other way will access the methods. I feel this has to do with the different types of socket objects one can make but I'm not so sure. I'll post my code just in case there are problems with something I wrote instead:

```
import socket
import os

class Sniff:
    def __init__(self, HOST):
        self.HOST = HOST
        self.sniffer = socket

    def sniff_packet(self, host, win, socket_prot):
        self.sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket_prot)
        self.sniffer.bind((host, 80))
        self.sniffer.setsocketopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

        if win == 1:
            self.sniffer.iotcl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

        print(self.sniffer.recvfrom(65565))


    def main(self):
        if os.name == 'nt':
            self.sniff_packet(self.HOST, 1, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
        else:
            self.sniff_packet(self.HOST, 0, socket.IPPROTO_IP)

sniffObj = Sniff(input("Enter your network address: "))
sniffObj.main()
```

Here are some errors that I get when I run this code depending on how I import socket:
1) `import socket`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PacketSniffer.py", line 28, in <module>
    sniffObj.main()
  File "PacketSniffer.py", line 25, in main
    self.sniff_packet(self.HOST, 0, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
  File "PacketSniffer.py", line 13, in sniff_packet
    self.sniffer.setsocketopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'setsocketopt'
```

2) `from socket import *`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PacketSniffer.py", line 28, in <module>
    sniffObj.main()
  File "PacketSniffer.py", line 25, in main
    self.sniff_packet(self.HOST, 0, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
AttributeError: type object 'socket' has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IP'
```

Please help me! I want to better understand sockets and how they work and I hope my question will help others who are stuck with the same issue as me.

Comment: Have you read the official tutorial chapter on modules? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: No, but thank you, Terry. I tried getting a friend to help me and he was able to make a packet sniffer and he imported socket by using `import socket`. I'm running Mac OSX El Capitan which apparently has had some issues running python. Does anyone know if that is true or not?

Answer (score 4):

> Why are they so different?

The outputs of `dir(socket)` are different because `socket` is not the same object in the two cases.

```
>>> import socket
>>> type(socket)
<class 'module'>
>>> type(socket.socket)
<class 'type'>
```

vs.

```
>>> from socket import *
>>> type(socket)
<class 'type'>
```

`import socket` does not enter the [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) module's definitions in the current symbol table; it only enters the module `socket` there. Using the leading module name you can access the definitions, e. g. [`socket.socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-objects) (where the trailing `socket` is the socket objects' type).

`from socket import *` enters all the [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) module's definitions not beginning with an underscore in the current symbol table, so, just `socket` is the socket objects' type.